# Get all possible combinations of 3 values from n possible elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to get the list of all the possible combinations of 3 elements from a list of 30 items. I tried to use the following code, but it fails throwing an `OutOfMemoryError`. Is there any alternative approach which is more efficient than this?

```
val items = sqlContext.table(SOURCE_DB + "." + SOURCE_TABLE).
  select("item_id").distinct.cache

val items.take(1) // Compute cache before join

val itemCombinations = items.select($"item_id".alias("id_A")).
  join(
    items.select($"item_id".alias("id_B")), $"id_A".lt($"id_B")).
    join(
      items.select($"item_id".alias("id_C")), $"id_B".lt($"id_C"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach seems OK but might generate quite some overhead at the query execution level. Give that n is a fairly small number, we could do it using the Scala implementation directly:

```
val localItems = items.collect
val combinations = localItems.combinations(3)
```

The result is an `iterator` that can be consumed one element at the time, without significant memory overhead.

### Spark Version (edit)

Given the desire to make a Spark version of this, it could be possible to avoid the query planner (assuming that the issue is there), by dropping to RDD level. This is basically the same expression as the join in the question:

```
val items = sqlContext.table(SOURCE_DB + "." + SOURCE_TABLE).select("item_id").rdd

val combinations = items.cartesian(items).filter{case(x,y) => x<y}.cartesian(items).filter{case ((x,y),z) => y<z}
```

Running an equivalent code in my local machine:

```
val data = List.fill(1000)(scala.util.Random.nextInt(999))
val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(data)
val combinations = rdd.cartesian(rdd).filter{case(x,y) => x<y}.cartesian(rdd).filter{case ((x,y),z) => y<z}

combinations.count
// res5: Long = 165623528
```

Comment: your solution is correct, but what if I'd like my code to be future-proof and support a larger number of elements?

Comment: @Vektor88 see Spark/RDD version.

Comment: thanks for the RDD based version. I tried something like that before, but the problem seems to be related to how the rows are fetched from the table. 
The cartesian part is not really a problem, I ran an example similar to yours where data was defined as sc.parallelize(1 to 30) and it finished in few seconds

Comment: you could probably break the lineage by `checkpoint`ing the data after you get it from the db.

Comment: I surrendered to using the scala api, I was unable to understand what caused all these problems, but I'm quite sure it's related to the partitioning/shuffling of such a small dataset in the cluster.